How to solve VRP with pickups, deliveries and time windows using Google OR-Tools in C#?
here is my method combined VRP with pickups deliveries and time windows.
// starts here
public void VRP(DataModel data)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create Routing Index Manager
            RoutingIndexManager manager = new RoutingIndexManager(data.DistanceMatrix.GetLength(0), data.VehicleNumber, data.Depot);

            // Create Routing Model.
            RoutingModel routing = new RoutingModel(manager);

            // Create and register a transit callback.
            int transitCallbackIndex = routing.RegisterTransitCallback((long fromIndex, long toIndex) =>
            {
                // Convert from routing variable Index to
                // distance matrix NodeIndex.
                var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
                var toNode = manager.IndexToNode(toIndex);
                return data.DistanceMatrix[fromNode, toNode];
            });

            // Define cost of each arc.
            routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transitCallbackIndex);

            int transitCallbackIndextime = routing.RegisterTransitCallback((long fromIndex, long toIndex) =>
            {
                // Convert from routing variable Index to time
                // matrix NodeIndex.
                var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
                var toNode = manager.IndexToNode(toIndex);
                return data.TimeMatrix[fromNode, toNode];
            });
            routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transitCallbackIndextime);

            // Add Distance constraint.
            routing.AddDimension(transitCallbackIndex, 0, Int32.MaxValue,
                                 true, // start cumul to zero
                                 "Distance");

            RoutingDimension distanceDimension = routing.GetMutableDimension("Distance");
            distanceDimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100);

            //Define Transportation Requests.
            if (data.PickupsDeliveries != null)
            {
                Solver solver = routing.solver();
                for (int i = 0; i < data.PickupsDeliveries.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    long pickupIndex = manager.NodeToIndex(data.PickupsDeliveries[i][0]);
                    long deliveryIndex = manager.NodeToIndex(data.PickupsDeliveries[i][1]);
                    routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickupIndex, deliveryIndex);
                    solver.Add(solver.MakeEquality(routing.VehicleVar(pickupIndex), routing.VehicleVar(deliveryIndex)));
                    solver.Add(solver.MakeLessOrEqual(distanceDimension.CumulVar(pickupIndex),
                                                      distanceDimension.CumulVar(deliveryIndex)));
                }
            }

            if (data.TimeWindows != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.TimeWindows.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < data.TimeWindows.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        data.TimeWindows[i, j] *= 3600;
                    }
                }

                routing.AddDimension(transitCallbackIndextime, // transit callback
                 3600,                   // allow waiting time
                 Int32.MaxValue,                   // vehicle maximum capacities
                 false,                // start cumul to zero
                 "Time");
                RoutingDimension timeDimension = routing.GetMutableDimension("Time");

                // Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
                for (int i = 1; i < data.TimeWindows.GetLength(0); ++i)
                {
                    long index = manager.NodeToIndex(i);
                    timeDimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(data.TimeWindows[i, 0], data.TimeWindows[i, 1]);
                }
                // Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
                for (int i = 0; i < data.VehicleNumber; ++i)
                {
                    long index = routing.Start(i);
                    timeDimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(data.TimeWindows[0, 0], data.TimeWindows[0, 1]);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < data.VehicleNumber; ++i)
                {
                    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(timeDimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)));
                    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(timeDimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)));
                }
            }

            // Setting first solution heuristic.
            RoutingSearchParameters searchParameters = operations_research_constraint_solver.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters();
            searchParameters.FirstSolutionStrategy = FirstSolutionStrategy.Types.Value.PathCheapestArc;

            // Solve the problem.
            Assignment solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(searchParameters);

            if (solution != null)
            {
                // Print solution on console.
                PrintSolutionVRP(data, routing, manager, solution);
                PrintSolutionTW(data, routing, manager, solution);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

i'm getting solution as null most of the time, i want to optimize route with pickups deliveries and time windows, i doubt the above code is correct or not
also i need the delivery time of each stops
i've tried changing the adddimension parameters value, but still i'm not getting the correct solution.
I want to optimize route with pickup and deliveries and time windows using vrp solver OR tools.

Unrelated: catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; } - don't do that. 1. If you so need to, just throw; not throw ex;. (Seealso the Note in the throw statement ) 2. A catch block that only rethrows the exception should not be there in the first place.

but this is not my problem, i want to solve the vrp with time window and pickups deliveries

That's why I prefixed the comment with "Unrelated" ... :)
